# sql - count column depending on whether parents or children

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to get the sum of a column in certain conditions i.e. depending on whether a column is a parent with subtasks or just a parent with no subtasks. If a task is a parent with subtasks I only want the sum of the "complete" column of the subtasks. If a task is only a parent I would only want the sum of the complete column of the parent.  - but only if the tasks(parent or children) are all related to the same user.

E.g. In the following example table:

```
UserID | Parent_TaskID | TaskID  | Complete
------ | ------------- | ------  | --------
435    | 149329        | 161280  |   1
435    | 149330        | 210717  |   2
435    | 149330        | 228100  |   3
435    | 156991        | 149330  |   1
169    | 458764        | 546540  |   2
169    | 456842        | 546541  |   2
169    | 456842        | 458764  |   0
```

TaskID 149330 is a parent with children 210717 & 228100 so the count for that column for 149330 is 5, i.e. ignoring the complete column for the parent. 161280 is a parent so only would return 0 for that. 546540 is a subtask of 458764, so 458764 would have a sum of 2.

So I think what I the result of this should look like:

```
TaskID  |  Sum_complete
------- |  ------------
161280  |  1
149330  |  5
546541  |  2
458764  |  2
```

Any ideas how this could be done?

I've created a table at SqlFiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8295f

Thanks,

I can get the parents by using the following:

```
select t.taskID, t.Parent_taskID, t.userID, t.complete 
from task t
where t.Parent_taskID not in (
    select tp.taskID
    from task tp
    where tp.userID = t.userID 
)
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: You tagged your question with tsql, but your fiddle is for MySQL. What RDBMS and version are you using?

Comment: Oh right sorry I'm using SQL Server... 2005

Comment: @HABO - I can get the parents with the additional bit to the question, I was thinking of a union getting children, if their parent id wasn't in the first query...not sure.

Comment: It should be noted that the Fiddle sample data doesn't match the data in the question.

Comment: Not clear.  In text you state 0 for 161280 but in table it is 1.  Is that final select for parent with no children?  With if a parent with not children has more than one userID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description, I think you are asking for the following (using the sample data from the question):

**EDIT**: Replaced query to eliminate children from the resultset.

```
declare @Task as Table
  ( UserId varchar(6), Parent_TaskId varchar(13), TaskId varchar(6), Complete integer );

INSERT INTO @Task ( UserId, Parent_TaskId, TaskId, Complete ) VALUES
    ('435', '149329', '161280', 1 ),
    ('435', '149330', '210717', 2 ),
    ('435', '149330', '228100', 3 ),
    ('435', '156991', '149330', 1 ),
    ('169', '458764', '546540', 2 ),
    ('169', '456842', '546541', 2 ),
    ('169', '456842', '458764', 0 );

; with QualifiedTasks as (
  select UserId, TaskId, Parent_TaskId, Complete,
    case when exists ( select 42 from @Task where Parent_TaskId = O.TaskId ) then 1 else 0 end as Parent,
    case when exists ( select 42 from @Task where O.Parent_TaskId = TaskId ) then 1 else 0 end as Child, -- Unused, but here for completeness.
    case when not exists ( select 42 from @Task where Parent_TaskId = O.TaskId or O.Parent_TaskId = TaskId ) then 1 else 0 end as Loner  
    from @Task as O )
  select L.TaskID, Sum( Coalesce( R.Complete, L.Complete ) ) as Sum_Complete
    from QualifiedTasks as L left outer join
      QualifiedTasks as R on R.Parent_TaskId = L.TaskId and R.UserId = L.UserId
    where L.Parent = 1 or L.Loner = 1
    group by L.TaskId;
```

A couple of obvious optimizations spring to mind.  The `Parent`, `Child` and `Loner` columns are redundant, any of the three can be eliminated.  `Parent` can be determined in the summary query by `Max( R.Complete ) is not NULL`.  A clever trick for `Child` or `Loner` escapes me at the moment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer but there only are 4 primary tasks: 161280, 149330, 546541, 458764  ..the rest all have primary keys which are in the task id list. 210717 & 228100 are subtasks of 149300. 546540 is a subtask of 458764.

Comment: @thegunner - Got it, only parents and loners are output.  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (though the data you posted on your question is different than the one on the fiddle):

```
SELECT ISNULL(B.taskId,A.TaskId) TaskId, SUM(A.Complete) Complete
FROM Task A
LEFT JOIN Task B
ON A.Parent_TaskID = B.taskId
GROUP BY ISNULL(B.taskId,A.TaskId)
```

Comment: So close...couldn't seem to get isnull working but if I use coalesce instead of isnull and change ON A.Parent_TaskID to   ON A.Parent_TaskID = B.taskId and A.UserID = B.UserID then it almost works!..

Comment: @thegunner: By adding just one more outer join and a WHERE condition, you could make this solution work, I think: `... LEFT JOIN Task C ON A.TaskId = C.Parent_taskId WHERE C.TaskId IS NULL ...`.